# How do you set a character limit for get string answers in C?

Tags: c, string, cs50, character-limit

I'm a beginner to coding and recently came across a simple issue that I cannot find the solution to on stack overflow, nor google.

```
string m = get_string("Something: ");
```

I don't know much code so I resulted to google and stackoverflow which both didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: What is "get string"? Please provide an example of your code (a [mre]) so we can help you.

Comment: string m = get_string("Something: "); How do I set a character limit for m?

Comment: Is this a [tag:cs50] question?

Comment: yes, this is part of cs50

Comment: `get_string` doesn't let you set the character limit. Why would you want an arbitrary limit anyway?

Comment: You can not! See [this excellent general explination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/2472827).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly limit the number of characters read by [`get_string`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/get_string).

Instead, you can use [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) to check the length of the resulting string, i.e.,

```
string foo = get_string("enter a string: ");
size_t length = strlen(foo);

if (length > 24)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "String is too long!\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think get string should be scanf function. Below is an example of a simple input operation in C with a maximum of 5 characters:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char input[6]; // +1 for null char
    
    printf("> ");
    scanf("%5s", input);
    
    printf("The input: %s\n", input);
    
    return 0;
}
```